# JScrollPane Vertical Alignment

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Here is my function to handle the Components which is like to add to my Panels.

```
    public void addComp(JPanel thePanel, JComponent comp, int xPos, int yPos, int compWidth, int compHeight, int place, int stretch){

    GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    gridConstraints.gridx = xPos;
    gridConstraints.gridy = yPos;
    gridConstraints.gridwidth = compWidth;
    gridConstraints.gridheight = compHeight;
    gridConstraints.weightx = 1;
    //gridConstraints.weighty = 1;
    gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    gridConstraints.anchor = place;
    gridConstraints.fill = stretch;

    thePanel.add(comp, gridConstraints);

}
    JPanel contPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    JPanel elementBorder = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    elementBorder.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Element Ansicht"));
    JPanel buttonBorder = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    buttonBorder.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Funktionen"));

    JPanel mixedPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    addWinButt = new JButton("hinzuf\u00fcgen");
    delWinButt = new JButton("l\u00f6schen");
    editWinButt = new JButton("bearbeiten");
    listButt = new JButton("Material-Liste")

    winViewPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

now i put the Components i want into the Panel which will be given to the JScrollPane

```
    addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("PosNummer"), 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("Breite"), 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("H\u00f6he"), 2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("Anzahl"), 3, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);


    winselectedMap = new HashMap<String, JCheckBox>();

    for(int i = 0; i < selAssign.fgetArrayList().size();i++){
        addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel(selAssign.fgetArrayList().get(i).getPosNr()), 0, (i+1), 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
        addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("" + (int)selAssign.fgetArrayList().get(i).getTotalWidth()), 1, (i+1), 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
        addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("" + (int)selAssign.fgetArrayList().get(i).getTotalHeight()), 2, (i+1), 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
        addComp(winViewPanel, new JLabel("" + selAssign.fgetArrayList().get(i).getWindowCount()), 3, (i+1), 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
        JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox();
        box.setName("checkselWinBox" + i);
        winselectedMap.put(box.getName(), box);
        addComp(winViewPanel, box, 4, (i+1), 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    }

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(winViewPanel);

    scrollPane.setBorder(null);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(500, 600) );
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);

    buttonBorder.add(leftPanel);
    elementBorder.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    addComp(mixedPanel, buttonBorder, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(mixedPanel, elementBorder, 0, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.NONE);

    contPanel.add(mixedPanel);
```

Iam trying to set the My Components inside the JScrollPane, for some Reason it puts every Component into the Center of the SCrollPane, instead of starting from the Top.

Comment: GridBagLayout lays out from the centre of the container. You can apply a weighty if 1 to the last component, which will push all the other components to the top - I often use a filler component for this

Comment: that worked like a Charm, thanks alot and ill keep that tipp of urs in mind